# NAudio stream sampled 8-bit data

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, naudio

I'm trying to stream out and play audio data that comes in from a TCP:port.
Data is unsigned 8-bit and the data rate is 11.025KHz.

I have no problem receiving the data, but I need some help with the code to get the audio streaming to work with C# and NAudio.

Answer (score 2):

NAudio has [BufferedWaveProvider](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/BufferedWaveProvider.cs) class just for your purpose. You can use it like this:

```
var bufferedStream = new BufferedWaveProvider(format);
var waveOut = new WaveOut();
waveOut.Init(bufferedStream);
waveOut.Play();
```

And now you should supply buffered provider with your data (probably in another thread):

```
var buffer = GetData(); // Here is your code
bufferedStream.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Probably you'll want to check whether there is enough data in buffer, otherwise pause playback or something else.

[This tutorial](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html) explains how it works in NAuduo. And [here](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioDemo/Mp3StreamingDemo/MP3StreamingPanel.cs) is an example.